# Set task to run on system startup with cmd/schtasks

Tags: windows-task-scheduler

I am a bit confused on how to schedule a task to run on system startup as SYSTEM with schtasks command line and I have read MS's documentation on schtasks.exe. Can someone here help me.

Answer (score 14):

The following command schedules the MyApp program to run every time the system starts, beginning on March 15, 2001:
the date is optional.

```
schtasks /create /tn "My App" /tr c:\apps\myapp.exe /sc onstart /sd 03/15/2001
```

Comment: The user will be SYSTEM right? or do I need to specify it with the ru parameter?

Comment: the `/sd` parameter doesnt apply for `/sc onstart` for windows 10.

Answer (score 4):

Using /RU SYSTEM makes a task run as the system.

For additional info, see
http://support.microsoft.com/kb/814596

Answer (score 2):

You can specify account to use for both at task level as well as at command level.

`/U to specify user account that should be used to run the actual command
 /RU to specify user account that should be used to execute the scheduled task`

**By default** both would use "System" account i.e. with the permissions of the user logged in.

For more details: https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb490996.aspx

Comment: This is good to know.. For the best reliability, is it then best to run with `/ru SYSTEM /u SYSTEM`? Why are there 2 different settings and when do they matter?